# How to get CCTableView Cell child position

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have added one sprite to my layer , for that sprite i have added CCTableview  , in cellAtIndex method i have created menu item and added to table view cell.

Now i want to get those menu items position with respect to my layer. How to do it ?

I tried like this

```
CCPoint pos=item->getPosition(); // MENU ITEM 
pos=item->getParent()->convertToNodeSpace(pos);// CONVERTING TO  TABLEVIEW CELL NODE SPACE 
CCLog("item.x=%f",pos.y);

pos=this->stickerTableView->convertToNodeSpace(pos);

CCLog("item.x=%f",pos.y);
```

Comment: Are you calling this out in your scene or in the CCTableview code?

Comment: No, i am calling this inside the scene, where i have created table view